# How would I run this code at a certain window width in my web page?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var snapper = new Snap({
            element: document.getElementById('content'),
            disable: 'right'

        });
</script>
```

And I want it to run/be turned on only when the window width is less than or equal to 768px.  How would I do this with javascript?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `window.onresize` event.

```
window.onresize = function ()
    {
        if (window.innerWidth <= 768)
        {
            var snapper = new Snap({
                element: document.getElementById('content'),
                disable: 'right'

            });
        }

    }
```

Note that this will only fire when resizing of the window is complete, and that you may want to use jQuery's `$(window).width()` instead of pure javascript [since it can be a little wonky](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/browserwindow). Also, if you want to undo what you did in the above if statement, you'll want to attach an `else` block with the appropriate code. Finally, if optimization strikes your fancy and you want to avoid running unnecessary code (eg if the window is resized to 768 and subsequently 700, there's no reason to run the `if` block both times) you may want to set a flag that's checked by the `if` and `else if`  blocks (your `else` block would turn into an `else if`) to prevent creating a new `Snap` when it's not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `window.innerWidth` property to determine what the width of the viewport. Note that this *does* include the vertical scrollbar.

```
if(window.innerWidth <= 768) {
    // your code
}
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.innerWidth

Note that the `innerWidth` property is not available in versions of IE prior to IE9; Safari prior to Safari 3; and Opera prior to Opera 9.

Comment: Note that `innerWidth` is only supported by IE9+

Comment: Editing post to mention that.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using modernizr's [media query](http://modernizr.com/docs/#mq) functionaility to determine if you want to run this code or not.

You can do a media query just like in CSS, and then if it's true, run your code.

```
if(Modernizr.mq('(max-width: 767px)'){
    //your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With jquery you should be able to get the width and height of the window with

```
$(window).width();
$(window).height();
```

To do what you're after (If you're already using jquery)

```
$(window).resize(function() {
   if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
       //do your code
   }
   else {
       //go back to normal
  }
});
```